# Page redirect not working in php when accessed without a browser

Tags: php, browser, redirect, header, sms

I am developing an application in which the input I receive is through an SMS gateway ( and not a browser). I need to process the data obtained through SMS and pass it onto another PHP file which will finish the processing and send back an SMS to the SMS gateway.

However, when I try to redirect from page1.php to page2.php, it is not working with the following code:

page1.php:

```
$url = "location:http://www.iweavesolutions.com/$extra?sms=".$msg."&keyword=".$key."&num=".$msg_num."&src=".$source;
header($url);
```

page2.php:

```
$msg = $_GET['sms'];
$msg_num = $_GET['num'];
$keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
$src = $_GET['src'];
send_sms($msg,$msg_num);
```

However, the header call in the first page doesn't seem to work. php documentation says that header is used for browser related activities. In my application there is no browser at all. So, do I need to change my mechanism for passing values across files? Please help

Comment: and yes...it is working well on localhost

Comment: is there a reason for splitting the script into 2 files?

Comment: As far as i get is that you wanna send data to other page as query string, without opening a new page or any browser activity as you have mentioned? correct me if i miss understood?

Comment: @roman : yes. there is a reason for splitting code into multiple files. Actually, the code is a bit huge and we want it to be maintainable. Hence we have split it

Comment: If that's the only reason, the traditional way of doing this is an [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). This way you also don't need to expose application variables and therefore don't need to care about variable encoding and such.

Answer (score 2):

please refer to "CURL"

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.iweavesolutions.com");     
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'variable1=abc&variable2=123');     
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,1); 
$buffer = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

some thing like this

Comment: ofc Ajax can be another solution.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If CURL is not installed, Ajax is the only solution is it. Also, how does it work on localhost?

Comment: Do you want something in response from your site in "$url" ?

Comment: If the client (the SMS gateway) does not follow standard redirects, it is not very likely that it would execute JavaScript, so AJAX will likely not help here.

Comment: well it was actually followed using his question that "So, do I need to change my mechanism for passing values across files?". So i told just told him an option to send values among files.

Comment: @noobie-php: Sorry for the confusion - I deleted my comment on using CURL after realizing (to late) what you where aiming at.

Comment: no issue man as long as any 1 is getting clues on what to do i think it is fairly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sending a `location:[someUrl]` header as an answer to a request just tells the requesting client to do another request to that location. It is up to the client whether to follow this redirect or not. Browsers will usually do this, other clients may not.

If the client you're dealing with (the SMS gateway) does not follow location header redirects, you need to check with the clients documentation if there is some mechanism to make him do that. If there is no way to redirect the client, you need to change your server side logic to get rid of the need for the redirect, i.e. you need to call the processing logic in your 'page2.php' directly from 'page1.php' without the indirection of the redirect (or bundle the whole logic in one file, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The SMS gateway probably does not implement HTTP properly. IME this is not uncommon.

As a side note, your first script (assuming it is complete) is written assuming register_globals is enabled - this has been deprecated for a long time, and does not url-encode the values - which may be the cause of the issue here. If not, you'll need to either:

- fix the SMS gateway
- change the end point registered on the SMS gateway to eliminate the ned for redirection
- include the code from the redirected script into the current endpoint script
- proxy the request from the gateway in the endpoint script.